# AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, xml, python-requests

I'm trying to make a desktop notifier, and for that I'm scraping news from a site. When I run the program, I get the following error.

```
news[child.tag] = child.encode('utf8')
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

How do I resolve it? I'm completely new to this. I tried searching for solutions, but none of them worked for me.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


# url of news rss feed
RSS_FEED_URL = "http://www.hindustantimes.com/rss/topnews/rssfeed.xml"


def loadRSS():
    '''
    utility function to load RSS feed
    '''
    # create HTTP request response object
    resp = requests.get(RSS_FEED_URL)
    # return response content
    return resp.content


def parseXML(rss):
    '''
    utility function to parse XML format rss feed
    '''
    # create element tree root object
    root = ET.fromstring(rss)
    # create empty list for news items
    newsitems = []
    # iterate news items
    for item in root.findall('./channel/item'):
        news = {}
        # iterate child elements of item
        for child in item:
            # special checking for namespace object content:media
            if child.tag == '{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}content':
                news['media'] = child.attrib['url']
            else:
                news[child.tag] = child.encode('utf8')
        newsitems.append(news)
    # return news items list
    return newsitems


def topStories():
    '''
    main function to generate and return news items
    '''
    # load rss feed
    rss = loadRSS()
    # parse XML
    newsitems = parseXML(rss)
    return newsitems
```

Comment: i have not worked with xml, but the error says that `child` is not a string object. so before `encode` it seems to convert your `Element` instance `child` to some string.

Comment: simply checking [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element), how about `child.text.encode`?

Comment: Ya i did that too but i'm getting the same error @Leonard2

Comment: news[child.tag] = child.text.encode('utf8')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: I guess this problem can be data-dependent. I mean, it depends on whether each `child` has some text or not.

Comment: You can check the link from where i'm scraping.It contains text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to convert a `str` to `bytes`, and then store those bytes in a dictionary.
The problem is that the object you're doing this to is an
[`xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element),
not a `str`.

You probably meant to get the text from within or around that element, and then `encode()` *that*.
The docs
suggests using the
[`itertext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.itertext)
method:

```
''.join(child.itertext())
```

This will evaluate to a `str`, which you can then `encode()`.

Note that the
[`text` and `tail` attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text)
might not contain text
(emphasis added):

> Their values are usually strings **but may be any application-specific object**.

If you want to use those attributes, you'll have to handle `None` or non-string values:

```
head = '' if child.text is None else str(child.text)
tail = '' if child.text is None else str(child.text)
# Do something with head and tail...
```

Even this is not really enough.
If `text` or `tail` contain `bytes` objects of some unexpected
(or plain wrong)
encoding, this will raise a `UnicodeEncodeError`.

### Strings versus Bytes

I suggest leaving the text as a `str`, and not encoding it at all.
Encoding text to a `bytes` object is intended as the last step before writing it to a binary file, a network socket, or some other hardware.

For more on the difference between bytes and characters, see Ned Batchelder's
"[Pragmatic Unicode, or, How Do I Stop the Pain?](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)"
(36 minute [video from PyCon US 2012](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc)).
He covers both Python 2 and 3.

### Example Output

Using the `child.itertext()` method, and *not encoding the strings*, I got a reasonable-looking list-of-dictionaries from `topStories()`:

```
[
  ...,
  {'description': 'Ayushmann Khurrana says his five-year Bollywood journey has '
                  'been “a fun ride”; adds success is a lousy teacher while '
                  'failure is “your friend, philosopher and guide”.',
    'guid': 'http://www.hindustantimes.com/bollywood/i-am-a-hardcore-realist-and-that-s-why-i-feel-my-journey-has-been-a-joyride-ayushmann-khurrana/story-KQDR7gMuvhD9AeQTA7tbmI.html',
    'link': 'http://www.hindustantimes.com/bollywood/i-am-a-hardcore-realist-and-that-s-why-i-feel-my-journey-has-been-a-joyride-ayushmann-khurrana/story-KQDR7gMuvhD9AeQTA7tbmI.html',
    'media': 'http://www.hindustantimes.com/rf/image_size_630x354/HT/p2/2017/06/26/Pictures/actor-ayushman-khurana_24f064ae-5a5d-11e7-9d38-39c470df081e.JPG',
    'pubDate': 'Mon, 26 Jun 2017 10:50:26 GMT ',
    'title': "I am a hardcore realist, and that's why I&thinsp;feel my journey "
             'has been a joyride: Ayushmann...'},
]
```

Comment: when i write just child.text then i get the following error in my notification program      message.append(signature=signature, *args)
TypeError: Expected a string or unicode object

Comment: @ani:  I don't see `message.append` in your code anywhere.  Anyway, like I highlighted in my answer, `text` and `tail` can contain _any_ object, so don't assume they're text in any form, let alone Unicode strings.  (If you _did_ get `str` strings and then used the `encode()` method to convert them to `bytes`, see my update about leaving them as strings.)

Comment: No i'm using message.append in another program

Comment: when i'm using str(child.text) i'm getting the following error  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 136: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @ani:  Remember the bit that said "may be _any_ application-specific object"?  That includes "text" in unspecified (and possibly incorrect) encodings.  Are you _sure_ you can't get what you want from `itertext()`?  I added an example of the output I got from it.

Comment: Sorry,i did not see itertext().It's working now.Thank you so much