# AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'children'

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have this XML file:

```
<population>
    <person id="101">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="age" class="java.lang.Integer" >53</attribute>
        </attributes>
        <plan score="-0.38" selected="yes">
            <activity type="outside" link="81312" facility="outside_208" x="649324.9906891582" y="6866581.699995641" end_time="08:22:00" >
            </activity>
            <leg mode="car" dep_time="08:22:00" trav_time="00:10:13">
                <route type="links" start_link="81312" end_link="138852" trav_time="00:10:13" distance="6046.54932060571" vehicleRefId="7262234">81312</route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="work" link="138852" facility="38407" x="651680.6" y="6863892.5" start_time="08:45:22" end_time="17:15:22" >
                <attributes>
                    <attribute name="innerParis" class="java.lang.Boolean" >true</attribute>
                </attributes>
            </activity>
            <leg mode="car" dep_time="17:15:22" trav_time="00:07:05">
                <route type="links" start_link="138852" end_link="189898" trav_time="00:07:05" distance="4604.544053407517" vehicleRefId="7262234">138852</route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="outside" link="189898" facility="outside_249" x="648729.9598002436" y="6866057.250182923" end_time="17:20:35" >
            </activity>
        </plan>
        <plan score="-0.38" selected="no">
            <activity type="inside" link="81312" facility="outside_208" x="649324.9906891582" y="6866581.699995641" end_time="08:22:00" >
            </activity>
            <leg mode="bike" dep_time="08:22:00" trav_time="00:10:13">
                <route type="links" start_link="81312" end_link="138852" trav_time="00:10:13" distance="6046.54932060571" vehicleRefId="7262234">81312</route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="shopping" link="138852" facility="38407" x="651680.6" y="6863892.5" start_time="08:45:22" end_time="17:15:22" >
                <attributes>
                    <attribute name="innerParis" class="java.lang.Boolean" >true</attribute>
                </attributes>
            </activity>
            <leg mode="bike" dep_time="08:22:00" trav_time="00:10:13">
                <route type="links" start_link="81312" end_link="138852" trav_time="00:10:13" distance="6046.54932060571" vehicleRefId="7262234">81312</route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="work" link="138852" facility="38407" x="651680.6" y="6863892.5" start_time="08:45:22" end_time="17:15:22" >
                <attributes>
                    <attribute name="innerParis" class="java.lang.Boolean" >true</attribute>
                </attributes>
            </activity>
            <leg mode="pt" dep_time="17:15:22" trav_time="00:07:05">
                <route type="links" start_link="138852" end_link="189898" trav_time="00:07:05" distance="4604.544053407517" vehicleRefId="7262234">138852</route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="outside" link="189898" facility="outside_249" x="648729.9598002436" y="6866057.250182923" end_time="17:20:35" >
            </activity>
        </plan>
    </person>
    <person id="102">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="age" class="java.lang.Integer" >53</attribute>
        </attributes>
        <plan score="-0.38" selected="yes">
            <activity type="inside" link="81312" facility="outside_208" x="649324.9906891582" y="6866581.699995641" end_time="08:22:00" >
            </activity>
            <leg mode="bike" dep_time="08:22:00" trav_time="00:10:13">
                <route type="links" start_link="81312" end_link="138852" trav_time="00:10:13" distance="6046.54932060571" vehicleRefId="7262234">81312</route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="work" link="138852" facility="38407" x="651680.6" y="6863892.5" start_time="08:45:22" end_time="17:15:22" >
                <attributes>
                    <attribute name="innerParis" class="java.lang.Boolean" >true</attribute>
                </attributes>
            </activity>
            <leg mode="bike" dep_time="08:22:00" trav_time="00:10:13">
                <route type="links" start_link="81312" end_link="138852" trav_time="00:10:13" distance="6046.54932060571" vehicleRefId="7262234">81312</route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="work" link="138852" facility="38407" x="651680.6" y="6863892.5" start_time="08:45:22" end_time="17:15:22" >
                <attributes>
                    <attribute name="innerParis" class="java.lang.Boolean" >true</attribute>
                </attributes>
            </activity>
            <leg mode="pt" dep_time="17:15:22" trav_time="00:07:05">
                <route type="links" start_link="138852" end_link="189898" trav_time="00:07:05" distance="4604.544053407517" vehicleRefId="7262234">138852</route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="outside" link="189898" facility="outside_249" x="648729.9598002436" y="6866057.250182923" end_time="17:20:35" >
            </activity>
        </plan>
    </person>
    <person id="103">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="age" class="java.lang.Integer" >53</attribute>
        </attributes>
        <plan score="-0.38" selected="yes">
            <activity type="inside" link="81312" facility="outside_208" x="649324.9906891582" y="6866581.699995641" end_time="08:22:00" >
            </activity>
            <leg mode="bike" dep_time="08:22:00" trav_time="00:10:13">
                <route type="links" start_link="81312" end_link="138852" trav_time="00:10:13" distance="6046.54932060571" vehicleRefId="7262234">81312</route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="shopping" link="138852" facility="38407" x="651680.6" y="6863892.5" start_time="08:45:22" end_time="17:15:22" >
                <attributes>
                    <attribute name="innerParis" class="java.lang.Boolean" >true</attribute>
                </attributes>
            </activity>
            <leg mode="bike" dep_time="08:22:00" trav_time="00:10:13">
                <route type="links" start_link="81312" end_link="138852" trav_time="00:10:13" distance="6046.54932060571" vehicleRefId="7262234">81312</route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="work" link="138852" facility="38407" x="651680.6" y="6863892.5" start_time="08:45:22" end_time="17:15:22" >
                <attributes>
                    <attribute name="innerParis" class="java.lang.Boolean" >true</attribute>
                </attributes>
            </activity>
            <leg mode="pt" dep_time="17:15:22" trav_time="00:07:05">
                <route type="links" start_link="138852" end_link="189898" trav_time="00:07:05" distance="4604.544053407517" vehicleRefId="7262234">138852</route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="outside" link="189898" facility="outside_249" x="648729.9598002436" y="6866057.250182923" end_time="17:20:35" >
            </activity>
        </plan>
    </person>
</population>
```

My intention is to create a data frame with three columns; `activity type`, `leg mode`, and `route distance`. They should be filled up with the below-standing code.

I try this with the following code, but I receive the below standing error message:

```
import gzip
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd


data = gzip.open('file.xml.gz', 'r')

root = ET.parse(data).getroot()

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

for ent in root.findall('./person/plan[@selected="yes"]'):
    if ent.name == 'activity':
        d['type'].append(ent.get('type'))
    elif ent.name == 'leg':
        d['mode'].append(ent.get('mode'))
        for place in ent.children:
            if place.name=='route':
                d['distance'].append(place.get('distance'))
coords=pd.DataFrame(d)


AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'children'
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837742/attributeerror-xml-etree-elementtree-element-object-has-no-attribute-encode) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048678/attributeerror-xml-etree-elementtree-element-object-has-no-attribute-childr), but don't really know how to apply it to my problem.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below could help - I noticed that the activity element is one more than leg per `plan`, so adjustments have to be made to ensure there is a sync when extracting :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from itertools import zip_longest,chain
from collections import defaultdict

root = ET.parse('test.xml').getroot()

#key elements and tags to extract
elements = ['activity', 'leg', 'route']
tags = ['type', 'mode', 'distance']

box = []

for entry in root.findall(".//plan[@selected='yes']"):
    #keeping the defaultdict within the for loop ensures 
    #there is a new dictionary for every iteration
    #also allows us align each extaction per ``plan`` element
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for element, tag in zip(elements, tags):
        for ent in entry.findall(f".//{element}"):
            d[f"{element}_{tag}"].append(ent.attrib.get(tag))
    box.append(d)

flatten = chain.from_iterable

#activity results are more than leg mode and route
#zip longest helps pair them, without excluding any entry

flat_data = flatten(zip_longest(*ent.values()) for ent in box)
outcome = pd.DataFrame(flat_data, columns = d)

outcome
    activity_type   leg_mode    route_distance
0   outside           car   6046.54932060571
1   work              car   4604.544053407517
2   outside           None  None
3   inside            bike  6046.54932060571
4   work              bike  6046.54932060571
5   work              pt    4604.544053407517
6   outside           None  None
7   inside            bike  6046.54932060571
8   shopping          bike  6046.54932060571
9   work              pt    4604.544053407517
10  outside           None  None
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution! :D

Comment: This code worked perfectly fine on my laptop with a small dataset. If I try to run it on a cluster with a larger one I get confronted with the following error:   ```  outcome = pd.DataFrame(flat_data, columns = d)
  File "/cluster/apps/python/3.6.0/x86_64/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 325, in __init__
    raise TypeError("data argument can't be an iterator")
TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator```
Do you have a clue what might be causing it?

Comment: not sure... could you track what line on the code is raising the TypeError. a debugger could help